# Write an xml file from the specified node?

Tags: xml

This is my xml file

Input:

```
<world>

<patent>
  <xml>a</xml>
  <java>333</java>
  <jaxb>111</jaxb>
</patent>

</world>
```

I need the read the above xml file and reproduce the following the output

Output:

```
   <patent>
          <xml>a</xml>
          <java>333</java>
          <jaxb>111</jaxb>
     </patent>
```

I dont need the world element. How to achieve this using Xpath.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: when you say XPath, do you mean you're using XSLT? What language are you using for the procedure?

Comment: its c#, and am not using xslt? And if not xpath, in general can u provide me a c# code to achieve the above output?

Comment: am not using the xslt? actually i need to read the particular node as mentioned in the output and save it as a new xml file

Comment: XPath is only a xml query language. In C# you'd want to select the `<patent>` element using an XPath like `//patent`, and then copy the contents to a file.

Comment: This is the code i used

XPathDocument xdoc = new XPathDocument(@"e://file_1.xml");
            XPathNavigator xnav = xdoc.CreateNavigator();
            xnav.Select("//path");         
            Console.WriteLine(xnav.ToString());

but i couldnt get he above output. Only the values are obtained instead the whole node elemnt?

Answer (score 0):

If we're doing this with XSLT 2.0, we can just use the `<xsl:result-document>` element.

It would look something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="patent">
   <xsl:result-document href="output.xml" format="xml">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="world">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
<xsl:template>

<!-- identity template here -->
```